# How to work with Not NULL in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

My query in SQL Server 2008

```
select DISTINCT 
    Fabric, Size_Range, Solid_yarn, Color, Per_Total 
from 
    tbl_Pgm_Creation 
where 
    Per_Total is not null
```

and the output is

[image: output bug]

Why the NULL value is returning???

Is that my query is wrong??

Comment: Are you sure `Per_Total` is a number ?

Comment: every field is varchar

Comment: `NULL` != empty string. Are you sure the data contains `NULL`s and not empty strings? (Or even just strings only containing whitespace)

Comment: So check if `Per_Total` is different from "" (empty string). If it was null you'd have "null" written in the cell.

Comment: yeah understood ... answer given by @ItsPete worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the field is VARCHAR, you'll need to check for empty strings too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fabric, Size_Range, Solid_yarn, Color, Per_Total
FROM tbl_Pgm_Creation
WHERE (Per_Total is not null OR Per_Total <> '')
```

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPT can be used: it handles NULLs cleanly. It also removes duplicates

```
SELECT Fabric, Size_Range, Solid_yarn, Color, Per_Total
FROM tbl_Pgm_Creation
EXCEPT
SELECT Fabric, Size_Range, Solid_yarn, Color, Per_Total
FROM tbl_Pgm_Creation
WHERE Per_Total is null
EXCEPT
SELECT Fabric, Size_Range, Solid_yarn, Color, Per_Total
FROM tbl_Pgm_Creation
WHERE Per_Total = ''
```